# Outlook 2011, where are located messages placed in "On my computer"?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I'm using Outlook 2011 under OS X Mavericks.
I moved some messages to my Exchange account to folders located in the section "On my computer".

I need to know where these messages are physically located on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out your personal folder (user) and navigate to:

- Documents
- **Microsoft User Data**
- Office 2011 Identies
- Main Identity

Please note that Outlook 2011 does not use a **.PST** file format

Comment: Just a simple footnote... the name of directory "Microsoft User Data" is localized... just in case your OS is not an english version and you happen not to find it :-P